# Remove certain nodes in copy of node

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How do I copy an entire element but remove only some of the children?
I want to copy the `div#about` but I want to remove the `table` elements from it.

Input HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content-header">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <table>...</table>
      <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <table>...</table>
      <p>The end</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div class="article">
            <h1>
              <xsl:value select="//div[@class='content-header']/h1/text()"/>
            </h1>

            <div>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@id='about']"/>
               <!-- Here should render the entire div#about without the tables -->
            </div>

        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the identity template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(Or, if you were using XSLT 3.0, you could use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` instead)

Then add another template to ignore the `table` elements

```
<xsl:template match="div[@id='about']/table" />
```

And finally, replace your `xsl:copy-of` with `xsl:apply-templates` to allow these templates to be matched, thus ensuring the `table` elements do not get copied.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@id='about']/table" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div class="article">
            <h1>
              <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='content-header']/h1/text()"/>
            </h1>
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//div[@id='about']"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```